# Картинка в header'е (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как сделать что-бы при уменьшении размера пикча не съезжала? (без использования медиа запросов)

```
        <div class="header">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <a class="top" href="#">ABOUT</a>
                <a class="top" href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
                <a class="top" href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="contactbtn"><a class="onbtn">Привет</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Header CSS:

```
.header{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #afafaf;
}
.header:before{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 125px;
  margin: -1px auto 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #eeeeee;
  border: 1px solid #afafaf;
  border-top: none;
}
```

Logo CSS:

```
.logo{
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например:

```css
.header{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #afafaf;
}
.header:before{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 125px;
  margin: -1px auto 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #eeeeee;
  border: 1px solid #afafaf;
  border-top: none;
}

.logo-wrap {
  width: 180px;
  height: 125px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.logo{
    /* width: 25%;
    height: auto; */
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  
  <div class="header">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
      <a class="top" href="#">ABOUT</a>
      <a class="top" href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
      <a class="top" href="#">CONTACT</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="logo-wrap">
        <img src="http://www.fancyicons.com/download/?id=6011&t=png&s=256" class="logo img-responsive">
      </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="contactbtn"><a class="onbtn">Привет</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```